# Conceptual understanding of effect of standardizing after normalization for clustering

Tags: clustering, normalization, standardization

My general understanding is that, before running a clustering algorithm, one typically wants to consider trying to normalize or standardize the data depending on its content and use. In my case, I have a problem where standardizing features (centering and dividing by standard deviation) *after* l2 normalizing across the rows resulted in much better clusters. I have never heard anyone suggest to do *both* and only by happenstance did it myself. I'd like to better understand in which cases this might be sensible, what it means that it worked, or if this was just perhaps luck?

My particular use case is I have something that resembles a typical recommender problem where I have rows (items) by columns (proportional user interaction with each item). I run truncated SVD on that huge set of columns (the user interactions) to get 300-lenght item embeddings. After this step, the norming and scaling occurred. I then run K-Means clustering.

L2 norming makes sense to me in the context of recommender systems (I've heard it suggested before), but I'm not even sure what my data "means" by following it up with standardization. The difference in results was clear enough though.

Any way to better understand this is appreciated.

Comment: So, you removed differences in scale first, then you transferred the origin (of measuring the scale) into the emergent mean, and removed differences in scale once again. This looks a bit fancy. But why not? If you can defend the action, suggest a reason...

Comment: @ttnphns Just to make sure I'm not misleading, I l2 normed across the rows first. Then I removed differences in scale across the columns second. I actually have no theoretical defense of the action of particularly doing both is why I'm posting. It happened by accident but produced considerably better clusters. For instance without that second scaling step I'd end up with one cluster dominating but having poor meaningfulness (by human read), but in doing it that one cluster gets broken out into much clearer meaningful subgroups.